# celery error unrecognized errors on Windows

Tags: python, redis, celery, gevent

I am running `celery v4.3.0` on Windows 10 and therefore using `gevent` package.

However when running celery worker with this command `celery worker -A celery_blog -l info -c 5 gevent` I get this

```
usage: celery worker [options]
celery: error: unrecognized arguments: gevent
```

This works with `-l info -P gevent`. But I need to use `-c 5` flag with it.

How can I do it?